# Cocos2d-x how to use things in ui::Widget?

Tags: xcode, widget, cocos2d-x

Totally noob in cocos2dx here. I get to run the helloworld app (YAY!). But then I am trying to add the objects in Widget class. I tried

> using namespace cocos2d::ui::Widget;

but it just show error. "Expected namespace name" with arrow under the W of widget.

Halp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Widget` is base class for all ui widgets which is inside `cocos2d::ui` namespace so you need to use in this way :

```
using namespace cocos2d::ui;
```

instead of

```
using namespace cocos2d::ui::Widget;
```

In case if you want to avoid `using namespace` directive then you can access `Widget` by simply prepending namespace in this way  `cocos2d::ui::Widget`